# Webサーバx2、NFS、PHP、MySQL状況下で排他的処理を実現するには？

Tags: php, linux, mysql

お世話になります。

現在以下の４台のサーバでシステムを組んでいます。
・2台のWebサーバ（Linux。PHPの実行。１号機、２号機と呼称）
・1台のNFSサーバ（各Webサーバと接続）
・1台のMySQLサーバ（各Webサーバから接続）

このとき「片方のWebサーバでPHPの処理を実行中、
もう片方で同じスクリプトが実行され、処理が重複しないようにするために
処理を待機させる（もしくは断念させる）」ことは可能でしょうか。
（排他処理）

当初、プロセスが動いているかで判断しようとしたのですが
よく考えると１号機のプロセスを２号機で参照できないため
プロセスのあり／なしで判別できないことが分かりました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 物理的なサーバ(1号機、2号機)と、機能としてのサーバ(httpd, NFS, MySQL)がごっちゃになっているのが若干分かりづらいかと。NFSやMySQLはwebサーバに載っているのか、もしくは3台目以降として別のサーバがあるのか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。全て独立したサーバです。指摘を受け質問を編集致しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL上に自作のジョブ管理テーブルを持たせて、そちらで管理すればよいのではないでしょうか。
NFS上でロックファイルを作る案もありますが、ちょっと不安です（根拠はなく主観的なものです）。